# R nnet plot bug?

Tags: r, plot, nnet

I'm trying the library nnet with some simple examples.

```
library(MASS)
data(Boston)
boston = as.matrix(Boston)
library(nnet)
boston.nnet = nnet(medv~., data=Boston,rang=0.1,size=8,linout=T,maxit=1000)
```

It seems to work well, but when I try

```
plot(boston[,14],boston.nnet$fitted.values)
```

I get a plot like this
[image]

instead of the expected:
[image]
(from the exercises my teacher sent to me. You can also find this exercise in several websites).

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

I know there can be some variability but this is very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the expected output when I run the code, except that I replaced:

`plot(boston[,14],boston.nnet$fitted.values)`

with:

`plot(Boston[,14],boston.nnet$fitted.values)`

Since the dataset has a capital letter B. Maybe this is the problem?

Good luck!

Comment: OK, I forgot to copy the line boston = as.matrix(Boston), because it's also used as a matrix in other exercises.

Comment: Also works with a matrix:) But you have to adjust your function call:
`boston.nnet = nnet(medv~., data=boston,rang=0.1,size=8,linout=T,maxit=1000)`
Because in the function call you write 'Boston' with a capital letter, which should be lowercase.